# why my comment add multiple times? Laravel8 &Vue.js comment save multiple times

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is my comment vue file

```
  <div>
    <button @click="getComments()" class="btn btn-primary">
      댓글 불러오기 글번호 {{ post.id }}
    </button>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->

    <button
      @click="openWriteComment()"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      id="openModalBtn"
      data-bs-toggle="modal"
      data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
    >
      Write Comment
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="modalBox0"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="modalInput"
              value="댓글을 입력해 주세요."
              v-model="comment"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button @click="saveComment()" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn">
              Save changes
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <comment-item
      v-for="(comment, id) in comments.data"
      :key="id"
      :comment="comment"
      :getget="getComments"
    ></comment-item>

    <pagination
      @pageClicked="getPage($event)"
      v-if="comments.data != null"
      :links="comments.links"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import CommentItem from "./CommentItem.vue";
import Pagination from "./Pagination.vue";
export default {
  components: { CommentItem, Pagination },

  data() {
    return {
      comments: [],
      comment: "",
    };
  },

  props: ["post", "loginuser"],

  methods: {
    getPage(url) {
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then((res) => {
          this.comments = res.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },

    getComments() {
      axios
        .get("/commentlist/" + this.post.id)
        .then((res) => {
          this.comments = res.data;
          console.log(this.comments.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      // 서버에 현재 게시글의 댓글 리스트를 비동기적으로 요청
      // 즉 ,axios 를 이용해서 요청
      // 서버가 댓글 리스트 주면 , this.comments 에 할당.
    },

    openWriteComment() {
      $("#openModalBtn").on("click", function () {
        $("#modalBox0").modal("show");
      });
    },

    saveComment() {
      $("#saveBtn").on("click", () => {
        axios
          .post("/commentSave/" + this.post.id, {
            comment: document.getElementById("modalInput").value,
          })
          .then((res) => {
            this.getComments();
            this.comment = "";
            $("#modalBox0").modal("hide");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

this is my comment's controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{

    public function index_test()
    {
        /*
            select * 
            from comments
            where post_id = $post->id;
        */
        // return $post->comments;
        // post eloquent->class 에 comment 메서드를 구현해야함.
    }
    public function index($postId)
    {

        $comments = Comment::with('user')->where('post_id', $postId)->latest()->paginate(5);


        //지연로딩 필요한 이유
        //클라이언트에서는 $comments 가 갈때, with 안해주면 user와 연관된 정보가 안감

        return $comments;
        /*
            order by created_at desc;

        */
    }


    public function store(Request $request, $post)
    {
        $comments = new Comment();
        $request->validate(['comment' => 'required']);


        /*
 $this->valudate($request,['comment'=>'required'])
        */

        $comments->comment = $request->comment;
        $comments->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $comments->post_id = $post;

        $comments->save();



        return $comments;


        /*
            $comments =  Comment::create(['comment'=>request->input('comment'),
            'user_id'=> //로그인유저id
            ..
            ])
            return $comments;


            create 에 사용할수있는 칼럼은
            엘로컨트 모델 클래스에 protected $fillable 에 명시되야함.

        */
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)

    {
        $comments = Comment::find($id);
        $comments->comment = $request->commentInfo;
        $comments->save();



        return $comments;


        /*
                $comment->update(['comment'=>$request->input('comment')])
                할때도 , 칼럼들은 fillable에 있어야함

        */
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Comment::find($id)->delete();


        return 1;
    }
}
```

if i try to add comment,
first time i need to click save button twice. (if i click one time, nothing change)
and comments save twice

if i try to add comment second time,
i need to click save button twice.
and comments save third times

if i try to add comment third time,
i need to click save button twice.
and comments save fourth times (x4)

does anyone knows how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trigging the save button twice.
Try it like this:

```
<button @click.prevent="saveComment()" class="btn btn-primary">
     Save changes
</button>
```

Then in your method:

```
saveComment() {
    axios.post("/commentSave/" + this.post.id, {
       comment: this.comment,
    })
    .then((res) => {
       this.getComments();
       this.comment = "";
       $("#modalBox0").modal("hide");
     })
     .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
     });
   },
```

I also recommend you to avoid using JQuery in your Vue code. In-fact that will lead you to lose the full benefits of using Vue.

Comment: thanks a lot. but i can's understand with your answer's last line :: lead you to lose the full benefits of using Vue.  what benefits can i lose if i use JQuery with vue.js?

Comment: You must understand that this modern JS framworks exists to replace JQuery and give a better developing experience.

Comment: My advice was to never use them together (Better to remove JQuery for good)
ex: $("#saveBtn").on("click", () => {} ) , it can be replaced just by @click=
so basically, you will never need to access the DOM with getElementById..etc and all that crap 